# trying to set column widths while using fixed table headers

Tags: html, css

I need to have fixed table headers. I used code from

https://github.com/joshmarinacci/css-tables-demo/blob/master/test1.html

I can't seem to figure out how to set the individual widths of the columns. I believe it has something to do with the use of webkit.

I have the css and html in a jsfiddle at

https://jsfiddle.net/cmendla/g6dym70f/3/

```css
.scrolltable {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}

.scrolltable>.header {}

.scrolltable>.body {
  /*noinspection CssInvalidPropertyValue*/
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
}

th,
td {
  min-width: 150px;
}


/* an outside constraint to react against */

#constrainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#constrainer2 {
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#constrainer2 table {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#constrainer2 tbody {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}

#constrainer2 thead {
  display: table-row;
}


/* only styling below here */

#constrainer,
#constrainer2 {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

th {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-width: 1px;
}

td {
  border-width: 1px;
}

tr:first-child td {
  border-top-width: 0;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="constrainer">
  <div class="scrolltable">
    <table class="header">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="50px">ID</th>
          <th width="150px">Start time</th>
          <th width="150px">End time</th>
          <th width="150px">Sales order</th>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Number of rolls fill</th>
          <th>Width fill</th>
          <th>Length fill</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="body">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="50px">ID</td>
            <td width="150px">Start time</td>
            <td width="150px">End time</td>
            <td width="150px">Sales order</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Number of rolls fill</td>
            <td>Width fill</td>
            <td>Length fill</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to make your cells a different size than your headers?

Comment: Adjust or remove `th, td {min-width: 150px;}` in the css it overrides the width  you set there.

Comment: @Jared - No, I want the headers and cells to be the same width. However, the CSS seems to make all of the columns the same width. For example, I only need ID to be 50px and want start_time to be 150px.   I noticed that I had         `th, td {min-width: 150px;  }` in the css. When I changed that to 50px, ALL of the columns go to 50 px. I have a new JSfiddle at  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cmendla/pc5nL5f7/1/)

Comment: You can set `style="min-width: 150px;"` on the th and td, rather than `width`.

Comment: @Pangloss - Thanks - That does exactly what I need. **You can set style="min-width: 150px;" on the th and td, rather than width.**